# Edit review on chrome webstore as developer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, review, chrome-web-store

Suppose I'm the developer of a chrome extension (which indeed I am) that is up on the web store and that I want to answer the review of one the users.

Now, if I add/edit my review my previous post gets overridden (even if I AM the developer), making my efforts in helping users useless.

Is there something I'm missing, or is it how it currently works without any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Comments is not a place to provide support for users, everybody can write only one comment per extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All reviews on the Chrome Web Store are from Google+ users now. Your best option is to click through to their profile and either send them an email, send them a message, or share a post with them. The first two are more direct and likely to get noticed but there isn't much else you can do.